# Custom dynamic TableViewCell text positioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a dynamic `TableView` that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjLCP.png).

However, I'd like to position the text more neatly, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufMyd.png).

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.0f]];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}
```

I've experimented with putting a label into the `TableViewCell` that's positioned where I want the dynamic text to be, but I've been unsuccessful in calling it in my code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom cell subclass. This subclass should have an `@property` in the .h file which makes your custom label available. In the .m (or XIB) you create (or connect) the label to the property (outlet).

Now, instead of using `cell.textLabel` you use `cell.customTextLabel`. Just remember to register the custom cell class against your `CellIdentifier`.

You can also configure the font and size on the label in the cell .m (or XIB) so you don't need to do it in code.

---

You will also want to change to:

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

so that the compiler knows that class the `cell` is (and thus what properties it has).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added a label and given it the class `myLabel`. In the `.h` file I've put `@property (nonatomic,strong) UILabel *myLabel;` and in the `.m` I've replaced each instance of `textLabel` with `myLabel`. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Class names should start with a capital letter. Are you getting a compiler warning saying that `myLabel is undefined`?

Comment: No, the error I get is on line 6 and says: `Property 'myLabel' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'`. Oddly enough the error was also on line 5 but it disappeared.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the same error really. See my edit (you need to set the class properly)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Coz, you want **just** change origin of your text. 
I recommend to add a `UILabel` to your cell as subview.

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"";
UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10,10,300,20)]; 
textLabel.text = @"Text here";
[cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
```

2-3 lines only and you needn't create a subclass.

Comment: It's best done using a subclass though. In your case, how do you reuse the cell efficiently?

Comment: @Wain ofc not so efficient as a subclass, Coz we can't reuse it. But this way does not require a lot of memory. UILabel is light weighted. So I want to say you're right, but different is not noticeable.

Comment: Zero memory difference. You still have a cell and a label. You could reuse your solution, for example by setting a custom tag on the label.